# Connect Kibana to Elasticsearch - ELASTICSEARCH_URL vs ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I don't know which environment variable to use:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana.example.org
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://ip-xxx-31-9-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://ip-xxx-31-9-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:9200
```

Should I be using `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` or `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS`?

Comment: as an aside, I can't figure out why it's not necessary to expose ports with kibana, it should require exposing port 5601?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the docker image of kibana **6.2.4** it has to be **ELASTICSEARCH_URL**. In the official [guide to configure kibana 6.2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.2/settings.html) the setting *ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS* is not even listed. This one came with later versions.